# Appropriate Location for Executable BitTorrent Sync in Debian 8.1?

Tags: networking, access-control, bittorrent

I am wondering if there is any good location for the executable of BitTorrent Sync. 
I have it many times at HOME but not sure if its the best way. Perhaps, some locals is better.

How would you execute BTsync in your system?

Comment: Better in what way in order to accomplish what?

Comment: Standard integrity of the system. There may be security gaps which I do not know.